# Method keyTyped in ClickListener is not working

Tags: java, libgdx

When im click my SelectBox and press some key, nothing happens.

```
sbNationality.addListener(new ClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(InputEvent event, char character) {
        System.out.println(character);
        return super.keyTyped(event, character);
    }
});
```

Im doing something wrong?

Comment: I see that you posted this question using an unregistered account, and then used a different account to try to reply to the answer below by editing it. A better bet is to sign in using the account that originally created this question - then you'll be able to reply via comments. [More information on logging into or registering an unregistered account can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account)

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation ([SelectBox.addListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#addListener-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener-)), this element seems to reacting only to 'touch' and 'click' related events, not to keyboard related events.

Perhaps you could try and use the stage events instead.